# Angular ng-content different behaviour while using select

Tags: angular

As we know using ng-content projects content only in last matched ng-content, but the thing I dont understand is that why does it behave the opposite while using select and projects only into the first one.

*First Child Component*

```
1
<ng-content select=".my-class"></ng-content> <br>
2
<ng-content select=".my-class"></ng-content>
```

*Second Child Component*

```
1
<ng-content></ng-content> <br>
2
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

*Parent Component*

```
<app-first>
    <ng-container class="my-class">CHILD</ng-container>
</app-first>

<br>--------<br>

<app-second>
    <ng-container class="my-class">CHILD</ng-container>
</app-second>
```

*Result*

```
1 CHILD
2
--------
1
2 CHILD
```

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rlmnsh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Yes, that was the question. Then why does it project content into last ng-content while not using select. I think expected would be to get the same result, as in these both examples first ng-content is matched

Comment: This is inconsistent and largely arbitrary behavior AFAICT. Given that in both cases the code is semantically wrong and likely represents a bug it makes little difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular compiler calculates so called `ngContentIndex`. You can think of it as a place where transcluded node should be projected.

So, having `AppComponent` template

```
<app-first>
    <ng-container class="my-class">CHILD</ng-container>
</app-first>

<br>--------<br>

<app-second>
    <ng-container class="my-class">CHILD</ng-container>
</app-second>
```

Angular gives each node its `ngContentIndex`(take a look at parentheses):

```
<app-first>(null)
    <ng-container class="my-class">CHILD</ng-container>(1)
</app-first>

<br>--------<br>(null)

<app-second>(null)
    <ng-container class="my-class">CHILD</ng-container>(0)
</app-second>
```

It means that first `CHILD` should go to second ng-content and the second `CHILD` to the first.

### Why did it happen like this?

The asnwer lies in source code of Angular compiler.

By default `<ng-content></ng-content>` is the same as

```
<ng-content select="*"></ng-content>
```

For each template Angular knows all its `ngContentSelectors`:

```
FirstComponent ['*', '*']

SecondComponent ['.my-class', '.my-class']
```

And here is [the answer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1f956184c426814be8fcbdab03396c910e29d935/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L863-L873):

```
const ngContentSelectors = component.directive.template !.ngContentSelectors;
for (let i = 0; i < ngContentSelectors.length; i++) {
  const selector = ngContentSelectors[i];
  if (selector === '*') {
    wildcardNgContentIndex = i;
  } else {
    matcher.addSelectables(CssSelector.parse(ngContentSelectors[i]), i);
  }
}
```

You can see that Angular treats `*` specially and updates `wildcardNgContentIndex` in a loop so that it will be `1`. For `['.my-class', '.my-class']` array it adds selectors to matches.

Finally, Angular uses [this method](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1f956184c426814be8fcbdab03396c910e29d935/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L880-L891):

```
findNgContentIndex(selector: CssSelector): number | null {
  const ngContentIndices: number[] = [];
  this._ngContentIndexMatcher.match(selector, (selector, ngContentIndex) => {
    ngContentIndices.push(ngContentIndex);
  });
  ngContentIndices.sort();
  if (this._wildcardNgContentIndex != null) {
    ngContentIndices.push(this._wildcardNgContentIndex);
  }
  return ngContentIndices.length > 0 ? ngContentIndices[0] : null;
}
```

which will return saved `1` value for projectable node in `FirstComponent`.